# UDP non blocking write failure

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp, nonblocking

I have worked in non blocking TCP, in that both read and write can fail in non blocking case. TCP non blocking read can fail if there is no data available and TCP write can fail if peer side`s TCP buffer is full (I hope TCP buffer size is 64K).

Similarly UDP read (`recvfrom`) can fail if no data available. But what is the failure case for UDP write (`sendto`). I think in UDP write there will not be any non block error. Because TCP write sends data and wait for the ACK from other side. But this is not the case for UDP write it will just send and comes out and it doesnt wait for any ACK from peer side. If its not send to other side means its packet loss.

Whether my understanding of UDP non blocking write is correct ? Please explain ?

Comment: There could be many reasons. Did you check what is the value of errno when you get write failure ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most likely reason why a UDP non-blocking send would fail is that the UDP socket's in-kernel outgoing-data buffer is full.  In this case, send()/sendto() would return -1 and errno would be set to EWOULDBLOCK.

Note that a non-blocking send()/sendto() doesn't actually send the data out the network device before it returns; rather it copies the data into an in-kernel buffer and returns immediately, and thereafter it is the kernel's responsibility to move that data out to the network as quickly as it can.  The outgoing-data buffer can become full if your program tries to send a lot of data at once, because the CPU can add your new data to the buffer much faster than the network hardware can forward the buffer's data out to the network.

If you get a -1/EWOULDBLOCK error, usually the most graceful way to handle it is to stop trying to send on that socket until the socket select()'s (or poll()'s, or etc) as ready-for-write.  When that happens, you know that the in-kernel buffer has been at least partially drained, and you can try the send()/sendto() call again.

Another (less likely) cause of an error from send() would be if the IP address you are trying to send to is invalid.  In any case, you should check errno and find out what the errno value is, as that will give you better insight into what is going wrong.

Btw the behavior described above is not unique to UDP, either; you can and will have the same problem with a non-blocking TCP socket (even if the remote peer's receive window is not full) if you try to send() data on the socket faster than the local network card can drain the socket's in-kernel buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> Because TCP write sends data and wait for the ACK from other side.

No it doesn't. It copies your data into the socket send buffer, and if that is full it either blocks or returns `-1/EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN.`

> But this is not the case for UDP write it will just send and comes out and it doesnt wait for any ACK from peer side.

No it doesn't. It copies your data into the socket send buffer, and if that is full it either blocks or returns `-1/EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN.`

In both cases the actual putting of bytes onto the wire is asynchronous to your program.