# UDP send buffer size guarantees

Tags: c, sockets, unix

When using a UDP socket in non-blocking mode, it seems that even if you are notified by `select` that you can write to the socket, [it may happen that doing so would cause an error returning `EWOULDBLOCK`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196064/udp-non-blocking-write-failure) because, as far as I understand, even tho there is space in the send buffer, there isn't enough to send the whole datagram you are trying to send.

Say you always send datagrams of the exact same size, would this guarantee that you are only notified of an available write when there is enough space available in the buffer? The way I see this is that while the send buffer is full the `select` would block as long as needed, and once a datagram is sent I will be notified by `select` and since all my datagrams are the same size, it means there is necessarily enough space in the buffer (because it just flushed a datagram of the same size as the new one I want to send).

EDIT: As @ikegami notes in the comments it isn't possible for `select` to know how large the datagrams you want to send are. I wonder if making the buffer size a multiple of the datagram size help? If the buffer size is a multiple of the datagram size, wouldn't it guarantee that when select notifies of an available write, it is guaranteed there is exactly enough space to write?

Comment: There is likely other network traffic than just this one process.

Comment: Re "*Say you always send datagrams of the exact same size, would this guarantee that you are only notified of an available write when there is enough space available in the buffer?*", If it's based on the size of the datagram (rather than the number of datagrams), then no. `select` has no way to know how big the datagram is. TCP works way better here since you can write a partial message, and use `select` to learn when you can add more.

Comment: @ikegami I see, thanks. Would making the buffer size a multiple of my datagram size help? Say my datagram size is 50 bytes and I make the buffer 200 bytes, I can send then send exactly up to 4 messages before a write would block (if the kernel did not send my messages in the meantime), then, wouldn't select only notify me when new space is available, and then I could be sure there is exactly enough space available? (ie: now there is 50 bytes available since a datagram has been flushed, which is exactly what I want)

Comment: On this subject tho I wonder if the specification guarantees setting the send buffer to a certain size either works perfectly (sets to the exact size you wanted) or not at all, OR if there is the possibility the kernel could for instance "round" the size you wanted to something a bit higher which would then become problematic for this idea since it wouldn't be possible to rely on the send size being a multiple of the datagram size.

Comment: @PopFlamingo I would expect the buffer to be far far larger than 200 bytes. And you're now asking about OS internals without mentioning OS and version.

Comment: @ikegami Sorry for the confusion, I should have said *the POSIX* specification, which would apply to multiple OS if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I wouldn't know, but I worked be extremely surprised if POSIX guarantees that